# iOS 8 bug with dismissViewControllerAnimated: completion: animation?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, ios8, modalviewcontroller

iOS documentation for `dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:` states:

> If you present several view controllers in succession, thus building a
>   stack of presented view controllers, calling this method on a view
>   controller lower in the stack dismisses its immediate child view
>   controller and all view controllers above that child on the stack.
>   When this happens, only the top-most view is dismissed in an animated
>   fashion; any intermediate view controllers are simply removed from the
>   stack. The top-most view is dismissed using its modal transition
>   style, which may differ from the styles used by other view controllers
>   lower in the stack.

This means when dismissing two modal view controllers at once using

`[[[self presentingViewController] presentingViewController] dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];`

the animation shown should be the top modal view being dismissed.

This is indeed the case in iOS 7 and prior, but in iOS 8 the animation shown is not the top-most view (in my experience, it's the second top-most view). Is this behavior a bug in iOS 8 or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Do you mean the top most view suddenly disappear at the beginning of the animation ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is a bug. It also happens if you do an unwind segue that goes back multiple controllers ( if I remember correctly, in that case, you do see the top view disappearing, but also briefly, the second to last controller).

Comment: Has a bug report been filed to Apple? I don't know how to do that or how to check.

Comment: I see the exact same issue in an unwind segue context. Help would be great.

Answer (score 3):

As commented above: I see the exact same issue in an unwind segue context. I just toke the workaround as described here using a screenshot and add it as a subview to all intermediate viewControllers: [How to dismiss a stack of modal view controllers with animation without flashing on screen any of the presented VCs between the top and bottom?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27042358/how-to-dismiss-a-stack-of-modal-view-controllers-with-animation-without-flashing)

```
    // this in during unwind in a custom UIStoryboardSegue (that is the reason why it might look wrong with what is what: srcViewController and destViewController
    UIViewController* aPresentedViewController = destViewController.presentedViewController;
    while (aPresentedViewController != nil) {
        if (aPresentedViewController == srcViewController) {
            break;
        }
        UIView *anotherSrcViewCopy = [srcViewController.view snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates: NO];
        anotherSrcViewCopy.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
        [aPresentedViewController.view addSubview:anotherSrcViewCopy];
        // recurse through the presentedViewController hierarchy
        aPresentedViewController = aPresentedViewController.presentedViewController;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Same problem and same solution here than @theguy.
Here's my version in Swift without iterating on all the view controllers :

```
guard
    let presentedViewController = segue.destination.presentedViewController,
    let viewToCopy              = segue.source.view.snapshotView(afterScreenUpdates: false)
else { return }

viewToCopy.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
presentedViewController.view.addSubview(viewToCopy)
```